# Pyarmor - Obfuscate a module and import it

Tags: python-3.x, obfuscation, pyarmor

I would like to use `pyarmor` to obfuscate the module in

```
main.py
module
  __init__.py
  func1.py
  func2.py
```

In `main.py` - which itself should not be obfuscated, I would like to import the obfuscated functions from the module.
So far, I only found solutions to obfuscate a whole folder including the `main.py` file.

Answer (score 1):

## Option 1

Just specify the folder you want to obfuscate .i.e.

```
pyarmor gen --recursive --output build/obfdist ./module
```

instead of:

```
pyarmor gen --recursive --output build/obfdist .
```

---

## Option 2

Another option is to use the `--exclude`

```
pyarmor gen --recursive --output build/obfdist --exclude ./main.py .
```

---

Which one to pick is dependent on the intention. Probably you need option 1. It means that if you add a sibling module to `main.py` (e.g. `main2.py`), it will not be obfuscated; with option 2 it will.

In both cases (a future `func3.py`) would be obfuscated.